# Troubleshooting Graphics Card Crashes - Dell XPS 1640 - ATI Radeon HD 3670 - Win 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, crash

On a somewhat frequent basis, my Dell XPS 1640's video card (ATI Radeon HD 3670) crashes. The screen will go black for a short while, then my desktop/running programs reappear. When I go into Windows 7's (64bit) Reliability Monitor, these errors are reported as "Video hardware error" (sample details below).

Frequently (but not always), Photoshop CS4 will be running when the crash occurs.

I have tried the driver available from ATI's web site. When using it instead of the Dell-provided driver, the crashes appear to occur less frequently but still occur.

Any ideas on the cause of this problem and how I could resolve it?

Thank you,
Ben

**Sample Error Report (values can vary between crashes)**

```
Description
A problem with your video hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033

Extra information about the problem
BCCode: 117
BCP1:   FFFFFA8007ADE4E0
BCP2:   FFFFF88003A2CC80
BCP3:   0000000000000000
BCP4:   0000000000000000
OS Version: 6_1_7600
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    256_1
```